# Wifi disconnecting automatically 20.04

Tags: 20.04, wireless

My wifi disconnects automatically at certain intervals. After I restart my laptop the wifi works fine. But I don't know what is the issue with my laptop. I have Windows and Ubuntu installed. Did not face any issue on Windows Wifi.  I'm new to Ubuntu, please help.

```
$lspci -knn | grep Net -A3

3:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6164 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0041] (rev 20)
Subsystem: Lenovo QCA6164 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:3545]
Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
04:00.0 Display controller [0380]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Venus XTX [Radeon HD 8890M / R9 M275X/M375X] [1002:6820] (rev 81)


$sudo lshw -C network

*-network                 
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: enp2s0
   version: 15
   serial: f0:76:1c:de:2c:9c
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.13.0-28-generic firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
   resources: irq:18 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:d1304000-d1304fff memory:d1300000-d1303fff


*-network
   description: Wireless interface
   product: QCA6164 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: wlp3s0
   version: 20
   serial: b8:86:87:46:18:69
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=5.13.0-28-generic firmware=SW_RM.1.1.1-00157-QCARMSWPZ-1 ip=192.168.0.6 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:50 memory:d1000000-d11fffff

nmcli device wifi list

    IN-USE  BSSID              SSID                     MODE   CHAN  RATE        SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY    
*       00:05:1D:03:04:05  D-Link                   Infra  11    135 Mbit/s  89      ▂▄▆█  WPA1 WPA2   
        F8:C4:F3:B0:F2:F0  vijay                    Infra  11    270 Mbit/s  85      ▂▄▆█  WPA1 WPA2   
        14:6B:9A:C5:69:CC  Vishal_vk                Infra  11    130 Mbit/s  69      ▂▄▆_  WPA1 WPA2   
        F8:C4:F3:B0:F2:F4  vijay_5G                 Infra  157   270 Mbit/s  69      ▂▄▆_  WPA1 WPA2   
        BA:DD:71:E7:26:B4  shashikanth              Infra  3     270 Mbit/s  65      ▂▄▆_  WPA1 WPA2   
        E4:47:B3:90:22:28  rishi26                  Infra  4     270 Mbit/s  55      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2   
        B8:DD:71:F7:26:B6  shashikanth              Infra  56    270 Mbit/s  49      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2   
        F8:C4:F3:A5:A2:F4  Akash99                  Infra  1     270 Mbit/s  47      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2   
        14:6B:9A:C5:69:CE  Vishal_vk_5G             Infra  64    270 Mbit/s  47      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2   
        C0:06:C3:8D:1A:56  ACT101634871421          Infra  6     270 Mbit/s  42      ▂▄__  WPA2        
        F8:C4:F3:B7:D1:98  Pushpaka vimanam         Infra  11    270 Mbit/s  42      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2   
        1C:3B:F3:E5:5C:DA  Chiru1976                Infra  6     130 Mbit/s  40      ▂▄__  WPA2        
        20:34:FB:53:22:2F  Redmi                    Infra  12    117 Mbit/s  39      ▂▄__  WPA2        
        F8:C4:F3:A5:A2:F8  Akash99_5GHz             Infra  149   270 Mbit/s  32      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2   
        C8:5A:9F:94:50:AA  ZTE-pyuCbh               Infra  4     270 Mbit/s  29      ▂___  WPA1 WPA2   
        00:06:AE:F1:05:C0  JioPrivateNet            Infra  6     130 Mbit/s  25      ▂___  WPA2 802.1X 
        8C:E1:17:9A:2B:3E  Old_Man                  Infra  11    270 Mbit/s  25      ▂___  WPA1 WPA2   
        AC:67:06:76:75:29  An0kit-ss3ccA-Eth3r_CP3  Infra  10    54 Mbit/s   19      ▂___  WPA2 802.1X 
        C0:06:C3:8D:1A:58  ACT101634871421_5g       Infra  36    270 Mbit/s  19      ▂___  WPA2
```

Comment: After installing Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, it was working, and after one day some updates are there and I have installed them and the problem started.

Comment: Hi! According to your prior comment, it seems like there was a kernel upgrade. Maybe kernel 5.13 is not suiting your device. Please post the output of `uname -r` and try booting into an older kernel.

Comment: uname -r   >>>>>>    5.13.0-28-generic